# How to format XML string by means of C++.Net?

Tags: .net, xml, c++-cli

I have a string, in which there are plenty of XML code. I'd like to write this string to file so that it will be well-formatted (with indentation), like:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <style1>text</style1>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

instead of

```
<table><tr><td><style1>text</style1></td></tr></table>
```

As far as i understand, LINQ is the most easy way to do it, but LINQ presented only in C#/VB, isn't it? The point is i have to use only C++.NET. Is there any solution how to do that in the simplest way?

SOLUTION: so, here is solution for this topic

```
...
System::Xml::Linq::XDocument^ doc = System::Xml::Linq::XDocument::Parse(article_string);
formatted_string = doc->ToString();
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use LINQ itself at all. I'd just use an XML API - probably LINQ to XML. Don't be fooled - the "LINQ" in the term really just means it's an API which is designed to work really well with LINQ to Objects. You don't need any language integration to use it though.

Here's a *really* simple example in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Use XDocument.Load to load from a file
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<table><tr><td><style1>text</style1></td></tr></table>");
        doc.Save(Console.Out);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm850"?>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <style1>text</style1>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

(Ignore the `ibm850` encoding - that's just because that's the encoding that `Console.Out` declares on my system.)

LINQ to XML basically formats the XML automatically when you save it, unless you tell it not to.

You can do the whole thing in a single statement, if you just want to format a file:

```
XDocument.Load("input.xml").Save("output.xml");
```

I'm sure you can convert that C# to C++ :)

Comment: i tried, but have some problems (see my post above).

Comment: @ars: Was that exception when you had those *exact* three lines of code? I find it slightly hard to believe that LINQ to XML fails like that under C++... it's the same code, after all. Are you sure you didn't try it with a different document which might have been ill-formed? Can you post the full stack trace of the version using `Save`?

Comment: exactly this piece of code leads to an exception:  System::Xml::Linq::XDocument^ doc = gcnew System::Xml::Linq::XDocument();  
doc->Parse("<table><tr><td><style1>text</style1></td></tr></table>");  
doc->Save("output.xml");

Comment: how to do stack trace? "call stack", which provided by VS2013 contains nothing but my func, which run this code.

Comment: @ars: Ah, I see the problem now, I think - you're calling `Parse` as if it's an instance method. It's a *static* method which *returns* a document. You're basically creating an empty document, then parsing the text to create a second document that you're ignoring, then trying to save the empty document.